# Java AWT Graphics change drawString()'s background color

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, awt

When drawing characters with transparent parts, you can see the background color shining through. How can I change the fonts transparent parts to be white?

For example using this code, I get a [chess pawn with gray background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBX6M.png):

[image]

```
package org.some.package;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0 ,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
       
        //Font containing chess figures
        g.setFont(new Font("DejaVu Sans", Font.PLAIN, 100));

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("\u2659", 10, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.add(new Example());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What can I do to get it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS9pm.png)?

[image]

Comment: I don't think a simple solution exists. The transparent parts are not just those contained within the enclosed loops but also around the outside of the font as well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"I don't think a simple solution exists"* While true, the 'not quite simple' solution is the answer to the dupe. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: indeed!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with plain String drawings because of various reasons. The easiest solution would be to use Images instead of Strings; though if you really want to use Strings, you can also change the text color itself to identify a teamColor (Whichever you fancy).

Answer (score 0):

Just make an image of the picture you want and draw it to `10, 100`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how? Ok

Comment: Misunderstood your intent. Sorry.